# How to generate missing values for each employee for each day

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

```
CREATE TABLE `EmpWorkCount` (
      `emp_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `day` int(10) unsigned NOT NUL,
      `created_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `daycount` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Current Values in the table :

```
    emp_Id    |       day            | daycount  |
       1      |        0             |  10       |
       1      |        1             |  11       | 
       2      |        1             |  13       | 
       2      |        0             |  12       |
```

.

```
CREATE TABLE `Emp` (
      `emp_Id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `created_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      `updated_At` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

Emp Table looks like :

```
emp_Id    |       created_At            | updated_At            |
   1      |        2018-12-04 20:00:00  |  2018-12-04 20:00:00  |
   1      |        2018-12-04 20:00:00  |  2018-12-04 20:00:00  | 
   3      |        2018-12-04 20:00:00  |  2018-12-04 20:00:00  |
```

I need to run a query where I need a count of EmpWorkCount with different day values (0, 1, 2, 3) for each employee

```
    Select emp_Id, day_list.day, 
    IF(daycount = NULL, 0, daycount)  as daycount from (
        SELECT 0 day
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 1
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 2
           UNION ALL
           SELECT 3   )day_list 
      LEFT JOIN 
      select emp_Id, day, daycount from EmpWorkCount
   )
```

(my query is incorrect, but I don't know how I multiply these 4 values from day for each employee

this gives output for the emp_Id, day values present in the table e.g.

```
emp_Id    |       day            | daycount    |
   1      |        0             |  10         |
   1      |        1             |  11         | 
   2      |        1             |  13         |
   2      |        0             |  12         | 
   NULL   |        2             |  0          | 
   NULL   |        3             |  0          |
```

but if the database does not contain let's say emp_Id : 1 with day values = 2 or 3 these records don't appear with a count 0.

Output that I look for :

```
    emp_Id    |       day            | daycount    |
       1      |        0             |  10         |
       1      |        1             |  11         | 
       1      |        2             |  0          |
       1      |        3             |  0          | 
       2      |        1             |  13         |
       2      |        0             |  12         | 
       2      |        2             |  0          | 
       2      |        3             |  0          | 
       3      |        0             |  0          |
       3      |        1             |  0          | 
       3      |        2             |  0          | 
       3      |        3             |  0          |
```

How do I go about this one?

In my query I have not joined with Employee Table --> but the output should even contain Employees which do not have a entry in EmpWorkCount Table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must generate all possible (employee, day) pairs, so you must obtain employees list additionally, not only days list.

The query will be something like

```
SELECT emp_list.emp_Id, day_list.day, COALESCE(EmpWorkCount.daycount, 0) daycount
FROM ( SELECT 0 day
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 1
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 2
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 3 ) day_list 
JOIN ( SELECT emp_Id FROM EmpWorkCount 
       UNION 
       SELECT emp_Id FROM Emp ) emp_list
LEFT JOIN EmpWorkCount ON day_list.day = EmpWorkCount.day
                      AND emp_list.emp_Id = EmpWorkCount.emp_Id
/* ORDER BY 1, 2 */
```

Comment: Thank you, Akina. Don't you think SELECT DISTINCT emp_Id
FROM EmpWorkCount should be from Emp table.

Comment: @j10 As I see it's possible emp_id exists in one table and not exists on another and vice versa. So maybe we need to collect epmployees from both tables. Thank you! Answer corrected.